# Issue with installing Windows 8 on an iMac

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I own a MacBook Pro and a mid-2010 iMac.

I'm trying to install Windows 8 on a second partition on my iMac (currently running Snow Leopard), but I'm still having issues :

- I tried with BootCamp, but since my **DVD drive is not working**, I cannot complete the process
- The BootCamp Assistant doesn't display the option of creating a **bootable USB** (even though I tried to tweak its `info.plist`)
- I tried creating a bootable USB flash, using Windows 7 USB Download Tool on my MacBook Pro which is also running Windows 8 (+ Mac OS X Mountain Lion), but I can't get it to work (I'm seeing the initial Boot menu, with <kbd>Option</kbd>, but the flash drive doesn't show up; pressing <kbd>C</kbd> on startup didn't work either)
- Tried **booting from a third partition** but I'm stuck at the point of restoring the .iso to the partition (now it sees the iso as corrupt :S - whatever...)
- **Using Parallels/etc** is out of the question since I need the 64-bit Windows 8 version purely for Windows Phone Development purposes(and that would create issues with Hyper-V and Virtualization, regarding the Windows Phone Emulator)
- I even tried using some Screen Sharing software (e.g. TeamViewer) but it lags + the resolution is not properly adjusted.

So, any ideas?

I'm willing to try *anything*! (lol)

---

**P.S.** I've been through all of this trouble only to be able to develop for Windows Phone (and thus, using Windows 8) on a bigger screen - and no, I don't have any cable for that (nor am I sure it's doable given that the iMac has no Thunderbolt port). So, if you have any suggestions on that, they're perfectly welcome!